# how doI bind a textfield with form in j2me using lwuit?

Tags: java-me, textfield, lwuit

I have a problem in below code, this `frmChinese.append(txtField);` is not working for me.

What is the correct way to bind this text field with my form? The header files and libraries that I have used have also been mentioned.

```
package com.lbs;

import com.lbs.MidletSplashScreen;
import com.sun.lwuit.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.Button;
import com.sun.lwuit.Command;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.Image;

import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.Border;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;

public class Chinese extends Form implements ActionListener {
    Form frmChinese = null;
    Command cmdExit = null;
    TextField txtField = null;

    Chinese() {
        frmChinese = this;
        frmChinese.setTitle("Chinese");
        frmChinese.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.getStyle().setBgColor(0xFF5240);
        ShowUi();
        cmdExit = new Command("Exit");
        Command cmdBack = new Command("Back"); // new command with name Back
        frmChinese.addCommand(cmdExit);// add command in Form

        frmChinese.addCommand(cmdBack);// add command in Form
        frmChinese.setBackCommand(cmdBack); // setting back command 
        frmChinese.addCommandListener(this);  // register action listener in form

    }

    private void ShowUi() {
        txtField = new TextField("","Search", 20, TextField.ANY);
        frmChinese.append(txtField); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is te addComponent method from the Form Class. In lwuit the basic interface elements are Components. Adding this Components to your Form's Layout, you can built some cool designs.

Take a look here:

[LWUIT Layouts](http://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/layouts.html)